# How to Validate Input in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am trying to validate a input field. The input field should take only numbers, if not it will alert "input must be a number". And if the field is empty it will do nothing. But when I left the field empty it will aslo alert me. How can I fix this. 
Here is my code

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Gross Salary</label>
<div class="col-lg-8">
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Gross Salary" type="text"      name="gross_salary"id="tax4">
</div>
</div>
```

and javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var validate_int_taxid = function() {
    var tax = document.getElementById("tax4");
    var tax_id = parseFloat(tax.value);
    if (isNaN(tax_id)) {
        alert("Gross Salary  must be a Number");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Thank You

Comment: Why did you tag CSS and PHP for this question?

Comment: I'm not sure about this but probably isNaN() probably checks for empty and null values aswell

Comment: Thanks guys. I solve it by myself

    <script type="text/javascript">
  var validate_int_taxid = function() {
  var tax = document.getElementById("tax4");
  if(tax.value.length == 0)
   return true;
  var tax_id = parseFloat(tax.value);
  if (isNaN(tax_id)) {
   alert("Gross Salary  must be a Number");
   return false;
  }
  return true;
    }
    </script>

Comment: I am reallly sorry  Viswalinga Surya S

Answer (score 2):

make it like

```
var tax = document.getElementById("tax4");

if(tax.value!="") {
    var tax_id = parseFloat(tax.value);
    if (isNaN(tax_id)) {
       alert("Gross Salary  must be a Number");
       return false;
    }
    return true;
} else {

    return false;
    //do nothing

}
```

Here is [**a fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eLMsY/).

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var validate_int_taxid = function() {
    var tax = document.getElementById("tax4");
    if(tax.value!="" )
    {
    var tax_id = parseFloat(tax.value);

    if (isNaN(tax_id)) {
        alert("Gross Salary  must be a Number");
        return false;
    }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: @Girish..that was the right way..It will return true if it is not a number..Then why u downvote for it. I am not getting !!..

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var validate_int_taxid = function() {
    if (tax.value !="") {
        var tax_id = parseFloat(tax.value);
        if (isNaN(tax_id)) {
            alert("Gross Salary  must be a Number");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    } 
    return false;
}
</script>
```